# conditionally active rxjs observable rate limiter

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, rxjs6

I want to create a rate limiter for an observable that conditionally changes the way that it limits a value. The use case is for a downloader that is continually receiving new urls to download. I want to be able to queue up incoming urls and switch between two methods of queueing. The two methods are by limiting a rate (e.g. no more than 10 requests every 2 seconds) and by number of concurrent requests (e.g. no more than 10 requests can be fired at a time).

A simple rate limiter can be implemented like below (borrowed from [here](https://github.com/gsipos/rxjs-ratelimit/blob/master/src/rxjs-ratelimit.ts)):

```
const rateLimit = (limit, rate, scheduler = asyncScheduler) => {
  let tokens = limit
  const tokenChanged = new BehaviorSubject(tokens)
  const consumeToken = () => tokenChanged.next(--tokens)
  const renewToken = () => tokenChanged.next(++tokens)
  const availableTokens = tokenChanged.pipe(filter(() => tokens > 0))
  return source =>
    source.pipe(
      mergeMap(val =>
        availableTokens.pipe(
          take(1),
          map(() => {
            consumeToken()
            timer(rate, scheduler).subscribe(renewToken)
            return val
          })
        )
      )
    )
}
const o = urlSource.pipe(
  rateLimit(10, 2000),
  mergeMap(downloadUrl)
)
o.toPromise()
```

And this is a simple concurrent limiter:

```
const o = urlSource.pipe(
  mergeMap(downloadUrl, maxConcurrent)
)
o.toPromise()
```

Finally, I can create this combined switcher to choose which type of limiter to use:

```
const toggleableLimiter = (func, limit, rate, concurrent, toggleObservable) => {
  let useRateLimiter = true
  toggleObservable.subscribe(() => (useRateLimiter = !useRateLimiter))
  const rateLimiter = rateLimit(limit, rate)
  return source => {
    const operators = useRateLimiter
      ? [rateLimiter, mergeMap(func)]
      : [mergeMap(func, concurrent)]
    return source.pipe(...operators)
  }
}

const e = new EventEmitter()
const toggler = fromEvent(e, 'toggle')
const o = urlSource.pipe(
    toggleableLimiter(downloadUrl, 2, 1000, 2, toggler)
)
o.toPromise()
// using rate limiter
e.emit('toggle')
// incoming values now use concurrent limiter
```

This all works as a decent solution to my problem. I can toggle between two methods using an event emitter. The issue however, is that whatever has been passed to the `toggleableLimiter` *before* the event is emitted, will have to adhere to that limiter operator. What I want to know, is if I can conditionally keep values in a queue and choose how to limit the queued values on a whim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! I have a solution, unfortunately it involves handling the queue myself. I believe this is a necessity due to the nature of observables and backpressure, I found a lot of discussion on the topic in this [issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/71). In the past this could have been handled more simply with the `controlled` operator, but it is [deprecated](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/controlled.md). Instead I simply used a `timer` observable and wrapped `mergeMap`'s concurrency control myself (though `mergeMap` still manages concurrency internally as a safety measure.

```
const rateLimitToggle = (func, limit, rate, maxConcurrent, toggler) => {
  const rateTimer = Rx.timer(0, rate).pipe(ops.mapTo(true))
  return source =>
    new Rx.Observable(subscriber => {
      const concurrentLimiter = new Rx.Subject()
      // stateful vars
      const queue = []
      let inProgress = 0
      let closed = false

      const enqueue = val => {
        queue.push(val)
        concurrentLimiter.next()
      }
      const dequeue = useRateLimit => {
        const availableSlots = useRateLimit ? limit : maxConcurrent - inProgress
        const numberToDequeue = Math.min(availableSlots, queue.length)
        const nextVals = queue.splice(0, numberToDequeue)
        inProgress += availableSlots
        return nextVals
      }

      Rx.merge(Rx.of(true), toggler)
        .pipe(
          ops.switchMap(useRateLimiter => (useRateLimiter ? rateTimer : concurrentLimiter)),
          ops.takeWhile(() => !closed || queue.length),
          ops.mergeMap(dequeue),
          ops.mergeMap(val => func(val), maxConcurrent)
        )
        .subscribe(val => {
          inProgress--
          concurrentLimiter.next()
          subscriber.next(val)
        })

      source.subscribe({
        next(val) {
          enqueue(val)
        },
        complete() {
          closed = true
        }
      })
    })
}
```

example usage:

```
const timeout = n => val => {
  console.log('started', val)
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(val), n))
}

const emitter = new EventEmitter()
const toggler = Rx.fromEvent(emitter, 'useRateLimiter')
const downloader = Rx.range(0, 10).pipe(
  rateLimitToggle(timeout(1000), 2, 1000, 10, toggler)
)

downloader.subscribe(val => console.log('finished', val))
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('now use concurrentLimiter')
  emitter.emit('useRateLimiter', false)
}, 2000)
/* outputs:

  started 0
  started 1
  started 2
  started 3 // 0 - 3 all executed under rateLimiter
  finished 0
  finished 1
  now use concurrentLimiter
  started 4 // 4 - 9 executed under concurrentLimiter
  started 5
  started 6
  started 7
  started 8
  started 9
  finished 2
  finished 3
  finished 4
  finished 5
  finished 6
  finished 7
  finished 8
  finished 9
*/
```